# AngularJS $broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help me in my question. Why doesn't work function $broadcast when I call from parent controller and catch in the child controller?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl1',
                function ($scope) {
                    $scope.$broadcast('parent', 'Some data');
                });

        app.controller('ctrl2',
                function ($scope) {
                    $scope.$on('parent', function (event, data) {
                        console.log(data); // 'Some data'
                    });
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl1',
                function ($scope) {
                    $scope.$on("ready",function(){
                      $scope.$broadcast('parent', 'Some data');
                    });

                });

        app.controller('ctrl2',
                function ($scope) {
                    $scope.$on('parent', function (event, data) {
                       alert(data); // 'Some data'
                    });
                    $scope.$emit('ready');
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was very useful for me. Thx!

Comment: One question. Why emit must be on last line? And if move $emit upper than $scope.$on it is not works.

Comment: @DK3 basically you are doing an `emit` first when the child controller is ready then listening it from parent and then using it to broadcast again. This is absolutely not practical and bad practice. this cause two propagations. which is unnecessary.

Comment: @Maksim this method is working but this should not be considered for using in real applications because two propagations for a single method to work is unnecessary

Comment: if you do so Maksim then again it you were just broadcasting your message for parent when the listener was not ready for child scope

Comment: You should then do something like [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jsalaat/60x93g3j/5/) to achieve this condition. Or wrap it in a simple timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Change  `$scope.$broadcast('parent', 'Some data');`

to

```
 $scope.$broadcast('parent', {message:'Some data'});
```

Comment: No It is not necessary to send it as an object. see [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jsalaat/60x93g3j/2/), Its just the child is not ready for listening.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jsalaat/60x93g3j/2/) from your code. You were just broadcasting your message when the listener was not ready.

Just broadcast your message when the `controller2` is ready to listen.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl1',
  function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.$broadcast('parent', 'Some data');
    }, 0)
  });

app.controller('ctrl2',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('parent', function(event, data) {
      console.log(event, data); // 'Some data'
    });
  });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you have any alternative variants instead timeout?

Comment: Well `$timeout` is not necessary here but to wait for the `ctrl2` to be defined and come in its listening mode.

 Basically `ctrl2` is **inside** `ctrl1` and `ctrl1` needs to be defined properly for the view inside it.
now when the code inside `ctrl1` initiates the listener is not loaded and is not in its state

Comment: In the emit case timeout is not used [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jsalaat/60x93g3j/3/)

Comment: `emit` propagates it to the parent controllers and `broadcast` do this for their child. `emit` is working because the listener on top of it is ready.

Comment: @Maksim See [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jsalaat/60x93g3j/4/) to understand. its just that the broadcast is fired before the child is ready to listen.